# How to embolden specific text within multiple instances of parentheses in Google Apps Script?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, parentheses

I've been trying to write a Google Apps Script to search a document and change all instances of a parenthesis(including the parentheses themselves) from this:

```
Hello (C)world, nice to (D)meet you, You are (G) my sunshine, my (Em)only sunshine.
```

To this:

```
Hello **(C)**world, nice to **(D)**meet you, You are **(G)** my sunshine, my **(Em)** only sunshine.
```

I've done it successfully like so:

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Utilities')
      .addItem('Bold Parentheses', 'replaceParentheses')
      .addToUi();
};

function replaceParentheses() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();      

  var found = body.findText("\\(.+?\\)");
  while (found) {
    var elem = found.getElement();
    if (found.isPartial()) {
      var start = found.getStartOffset();
      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      elem.setBold(start, end, true);
    }
    else {
      elem.setBold(true);
    }
    found = body.findText("\\(.+?\\)", found);
  }
};
```

But am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

I am using this to embolden chord names in the parenthesis... so if there was a call and response in the lyrics and some lyrics had parenthesis around them - how would I exclude those parenthesis in this? In other words, how could I make a set of variables to always bolden like (A,B,C,A#,B#,C#,Ab,Bb,Cb,Am,Bm,Cm,Adim7,Bb7add9, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine to bold everything inside a parenthesis. But if you want to set a list of variables that should be bolded and forget about the rest you could try to create and array and plug it in the regEx.

You could change your code like so:

```js
function replaceParentheses() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();  
  var targetVariables = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A#']

  var searchPattern = "\\([" + targetVariables.join("|") + "].?\\)"


  var found = body.findText(searchPattern);
  while (found) {
    var elem = found.getElement();
    if (found.isPartial()) {
      var start = found.getStartOffset();
      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      elem.setBold(start, end, true);

    }
    else {
      elem.setBold(true);
    }
    found = body.findText(searchPattern, found);
  }
};
```

Take into consideration that now you only match with values that are inside of `targetVariables`, so for example:

> Hello (Caa)world (C) (A#), nice to (D)meet you, You are (G) my sunshine, my (Em)only sunshine.

Would be conveted to:

> Hello (Caa)world **(C)** **(A#)**, nice to (D)meet you, You are (G) my sunshine, my (Em)only sunshine.

Comment: The above code works great for emboldening up to two letters. Through trial and error I added a '+' between the period and question mark in the searchPattern variable to embolden all chords no matter how many characters. Like so `var searchPattern = "\\([" + targetVariables.join("|") + "].+?\\)"` So thank you! Now my question is: Is there a more efficient way to programmatically add Maj,m,#,b,dim,dim7,(b5) etc. to letters A-G instead of writing every possible chord name in the targetVariables variable? E.G. Am, Amaj7, E#(b5)9, etc.

Comment: I don't really know how chords work but if you know all the letter and all the possible appendix you could just create  for nested loop and solve this easily. Create an array with all the letters `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']` and an other array with all the appendices `['Maj','m','#','b','dim','dim7']` and in the nested loop concatenate all the possibilities. If you still have doubts you should open a new question so it can be properly answered.

Comment: Thank you @raserhin I will post that as a separate question. You answered mine completely and I thank you for that. I love learning via example so this was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later and I realized when asking another question about this that I don't need to store the chord names as variables as 99% of the time, just targeting anything in between two parentheses will work for my purposes. Here is my updated code to select an unlimited amount of letters/numbers whereas the Regex I was using before was limited to two. This works great!

```
function replaceParentheses() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();  
  


var searchPattern = "\\([^\)]+\\)"

  var found = body.findText(searchPattern);
  while (found) {
    var elem = found.getElement();
    if (found.isPartial()) {
      var start = found.getStartOffset();
      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      elem.setBold(start, end, true);

    }
    else {
      elem.setBold(true);
    }
    found = body.findText(searchPattern, found);
  }
};
```